# Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ and Let $T:W\to V'$ be a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**:Let $W$ be a subspace  of a vector space $V$ and  Let $T:W\to  V'$ be a linear map.
>
> Then which of the following is true
>
> 1)$T$ can be extended to a linear transformation  from $V$ to $V'$
>
> 2)$T$ is necessarily linear map from $V$ to $V'$
>
> 3)$Ker  T$ is not a subspace of $V$
>
> 4)$Im T$ is a subspace of $V$

**Solution**:

> 3) $Ker  T$ contains  elements of $W \subset V$
>
> So $Ker  T$ is subspace of $V$
>
> $4) Im  T$ contains  elements of $V '$
>
> So $Im  T$ is not subspace of $V$
>
> $2)T$ is not necessarily linear map from $V$ to $V'$
>
> $1)T$ can be extended to a linear transformation  from $V$ to $V'$

Am I doing right $?$

Comment: Erase "the" in (4) and it'll be slightly better, or much better: $\;\text{Im}\,(T)\subset V'\;$ so it is a subspace of $\;V\;$ iff $\;V'\subset V\;$ . All the rest is, imo, fine, though I wonder whether you must prove that.